# Duplicate site in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, url-routing, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-routing

I have a question, how to show 404 error if the page doesn't exist.For example if I have bloc.com and I add at the end of link bloc.com/?id=45 it redirects to the homepage but the page doesn't exists. In CodeIgniter exists a config :

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
```

If I change to FALSE it gives errors at utm tags, how to show 404 if the page is bloc.com/?=45 but work fine at utm tags.Please help me.

```
function show($id = 0) 
{   
    $date= $this->model->get_date($id);
    if($date)
    {
      ....
    }
    else
    {
        show_404();
    }
}
```

I edited my question.

Comment: in your main controller you would have a check to see if the ID is correct and contains the data to populate your page, if it is not then `show_404();`

Comment: Vinod VT,If I add at the end of link ?id=454 it redirects me to homepage

Comment: do you have any rule written in your routes.php file that could lead you to that problem? In fact, you shouldn't need to write show($id) if you're sending the params as a get var

Answer (score 1):

Would this not work?

```
public function show()
{
    if (isset($_GET['id']) )
    {
        if ( $check = $this->model->get_date($_GET['id']) )
        {
            ......
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'show_404()';
        }

    }
    else
    {
        echo 'no ID set';
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't just copy and paste, did you? I put this on my local install of CI, and I could visit "http://localhost/tests/index.php/blog/show/?id=1" and it would work

Comment: No, I didn't mean for the quotes but I couldn't edit the comment after I noticed.